# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package?

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror, relative-import

My code structure:

[image: code structure 1]

[image: code structure 2]

When I import model from accounts app to to_do app:

```
#in to_do/models.py
from ..accounts.models import Account
```

I have this error:

```
 File "/home/ghost/projects/django_projects/To_Do_App/to_do_list/to_do/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..accounts.models import Account
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to import my model this way `from accounts.models import Account`
and now it works, but pycharm says that's not corectly

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to have an `__init__.py` file in the parent directory. This is how python recognizes it as a package.

Comment: ```__init__.py```  file was added to Base directory (to_do_list directory) but i have the same error

Comment: I tried to import my model this way ```from accounts.models import Account``` and now it works, but pycharm says that's not corectly

Answer (score 0):

Appart from adding the `__init__.py` file you must use the `-m` switch when you run your code from the top directory that includes all your top packages for relative imports to work correctly - for instance

```
$ cd to_do_list/..
$ python -m to_do_list.manage # note no .py
```

However it would be best to stick with the absolute import in that case and run as:

```
$ cd to_do_list
$ python -m manage
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me reproduce your error:

```
Project_rootpath
--pkg
    __init__.py
    A.py
--pkg2
    __init__.py
    B.py
test_lib.py
```

In B.py

```
print("module name: ", __name__) 
from ..pkg import A
```

In test_lib.py

```
from pkg import A
from pkg2 import B
```

Run python test_lib.py

Error happened.

```
from ..pkg import A
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

`..pkg` refers to the Project_rootpath.

Since the script `test_lib.py` runs under workspace Project_rootpath, sys.path includes `xxx/Project_rootpath`. In this project, the top-level package is `pkg` and `pkg2`.  Project_rootpath can not be treated as a package.

To modify this problem, we can create a new package pkg0 and put pkg,pkg2 into pkg0.